# Automatic login issue with selenium/chrome headless mode

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, login-automation

I am trying to automate the login process to https://login.upstox.com using headless mode with selenium and chrome in python
Chrome Browser Version: 123.0.6312.58
chromedriver Version:123.0.6312.58
Selenium Version: 4.14.0

In headless mode it is not sending an OTP to my mobile and not moving to next page. But it is working fine without headless mode. Can someone please help me to make it work in headless mode? Thank you for your help in advance.

FYI: In firefox it is working fine with headless mode in windows but not working on linux. I have tried with edge but no luck.

Here is my python code

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from datetime import datetime
import requests


def init_chrome_webdriver():
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    driver_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'chromedriver.exe')
    service = Service(executable_path=driver_path,log_output="chromedriver.log")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
                         
    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

def automatic_login(config):

    url='https://login.upstox.com'
    driver = init_chrome_webdriver()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    phone = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input")
    phone.send_keys(config['phone'])
    page = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"body")
    page.screenshot("before.png")
    time.sleep(5)
    next = driver.find_element(By.ID,"getOtp")
    next.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    page = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"body")
    page.screenshot("after.png")
    driver.quit()

if __name__=='__main__':

    creds = {}
    creds['pass'] = ''
    creds['phone'] = 'xxxxxxxx'  #Replace with phone number

    automatic_login(creds)
```

Answer (score -1):

When I run into this problem, I set the screen size...especially when going headless...as such:

options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

(Use a dimension that will work out for you.)

One thing that will greatly help is taking a screenshot of the page you want to access in headless mode. I'm willing to bet that headful and headless modes produce a different layout.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with this setting but it did not work. I have also added the code for screen shots. In headless mode the click function is not working. Hence it is showing the same page even after the click.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).